# How to get last inserted contact number from the phone book android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

How can i fetch the last inserted contact number from the android phone book. I already done with the fetching all the unique contact numbers and its count from the database and i have also made a ContentObserver for listening the updates related to phone book.but now i want last inserted contact number. I am putting my whole code over here.

This is my code to fetch all the contacts :-

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                listNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
            }

            ArrayList<String> unique = removeDuplicates(listNumbers);
            for (String element : unique) {
                System.out.println(element);
            }

            sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (String item : unique) {
                if (sb.length() > 0) {
                    sb.append(',');
                }
                sb.append(item);
            }
            numbersString = sb.toString();
        //  Log.e("BUFFER", numbersString.toString());
            phones.close();
            Log.e("SIZE", unique.size() + "");
```

And Now this is the code for contentobserver :-

```
private ContentObserver mObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        final int currentCount = getContactCount();
        if (currentCount < mContactCount) {
            // DELETE HAPPEN.
            Log.e("STATUS===>", "Deletion");
        } else if (currentCount == mContactCount) {
            // UPDATE HAPPEN.
        } else {
            // INSERT HAPPEN.
            Log.e("STATUS===>", "Insertion");


        }
        mContactCount = currentCount;
    }
};
```

In onchange INSERT Condition i want that newly added contact number.

Comment: Android doesn't provide a way to do that. Most people I've talked to who wanted to do this ended up having to scan all the contacts again and figure out themselves what was different since the last time they scanned all the contacts.

Comment: Yes i did that with the way you have told and add some my logic and able to get the solution.